# Print Conditionals AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is how input is set up:

```
input type="number" ng-model="yourNum" placeholder="Enter a number here"
```

I want to now parse this numerical input and perform the modulo function on it, and then print a statement.

I know I can use the modulo function, I'm wondering how to print statements based on the result. Ex: if (yourNum % 3 == 0) print "hello"

I'm having trouble using ng-if

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to be completely remove from the DOM when your conditional statement is true you can utilize the [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive to conditionally include bits of HTML

```
<span ng-if="yourNum % 3 === 0">hello<span>
```

Or if you want it to always be there just hidden from the user you can use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

```
<span ng-show="yourNum % 3 === 0">hello<span>
```

JS does some auto type conversion for you so in this instance the comparison will work. Search for `js auto type conversion` if you want some more info on it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="number" ng-model="yourNum" placeholder="Enter a number here">
  <span ng-if="yourNum % 3 === 0">yo</span> 
  <span ng-if="yourNum % 4 === 0">hello</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Pardon the confusion - I'm really new to all this so my question is going to sound a bit dumb.

When I run the program using ng-show // ng-if, the html is not conditionally there - it's there from the outset. Even before I enter an input, "hello" shows up. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You have to properly close tags for the conditions to work. In the code you had in the comment before you were not closing the span tag `</span>`

Comment: that comment was a little premature, here's the actual code I'm using right now:

https://puu.sh/lyC8G/8a3c05eab1.png

(it's just hard formatting code in comments)

Comment: Do you have `ng-app `on the html tag? if it's on the head tag odd behavior will happen. I've added a working code snippet if that helps.

Comment: I tried replacing my code with yours and still same problem: 
https://puu.sh/lyCt4/3a35512d7b.png
Here's the code: https://puu.sh/lyCqk/c9b65aa0ce.png

Comment: it appears it has something to do with angular 1.0.7, do you have to use that version or can you use the latest?https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-change="onNumberChange()" ng-model="yourNum" />
<p>{{ error }}</p>
```

Java Script:

```
$scope.onNumberChange = function () {
    $scope.error = $scope.yourNum%3 === 0 ? 'some error' : '';
}
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vau5IrGDmEzhaNZehRVG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I need to do it in angularjs

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the help, clearly I was wrong! Much appreciated :)